# Python Multiprocess Logging with independent processes

Tags: python

Currently, Python's standard docs recommend using multiprocess Queues with QueueHandler/QueueListener to achieve multiprocess logging. However, as multiprocess Queues are implemented with unnamed pipes, there's no way for independent processes to share the same Queue.

I'm interested in other viable solutions; my personal thought is rather its possible to instead implement a Queue based on a named-pipe, which should allow the Queue to be shared across multiple independent processes.

Comment: The obvious answer is TCP/IP.  Python makes that very easy.

Comment: I got this to work using multiprocess BaseManager, which effectively implements a allows using a Queue through TCP/IP like you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Logging as normal works fine for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import uuid
import time
import multiprocessing
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='multiprocess.log', level=logging.DEBUG)


def act(p):
    start_time = time.monotonic()
    work()
    logging.info(f"{p} took {time.monotonic() - start_time:.3f} seconds")


def work(start_of_uuid='00000'):
    while True:
        uid = uuid.uuid4().hex
        if uid.startswith(start_of_uuid):
            return uid


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.monotonic()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1) as pool:
        pool.map(act, range(24))
    logging.info(f"Elapsed time overall was {time.monotonic() - start_time:.3f} seconds")
```

Generates in multiprocess.log:

```
INFO:root:5 took 0.048 seconds
INFO:root:9 took 2.191 seconds
INFO:root:6 took 3.581 seconds
INFO:root:11 took 4.800 seconds
INFO:root:14 took 0.295 seconds
INFO:root:8 took 5.361 seconds
INFO:root:1 took 5.577 seconds
INFO:root:3 took 10.739 seconds
INFO:root:15 took 5.605 seconds
INFO:root:2 took 16.118 seconds
INFO:root:4 took 16.931 seconds
INFO:root:20 took 3.577 seconds
INFO:root:16 took 15.270 seconds
INFO:root:13 took 17.115 seconds
INFO:root:21 took 4.529 seconds
INFO:root:22 took 4.715 seconds
INFO:root:23 took 4.897 seconds
INFO:root:10 took 25.925 seconds
INFO:root:12 took 24.482 seconds
INFO:root:18 took 16.629 seconds
INFO:root:0 took 28.958 seconds
INFO:root:19 took 20.696 seconds
INFO:root:7 took 34.055 seconds
INFO:root:17 took 36.142 seconds
INFO:root:Elapsed time overall was 41.827 seconds
```

Comment: Is it a problem when multiple processes writes to the same file at the same time, this happens to me.

Comment: I've not had a problem and the widespread use of syslog suggests that this is unlikely to be a problem.